# Invalid connection property value sslmode : require

Tags: amazon-redshift, dbeaver

I'm attempting to connect to Redshift. I've double checked my settings, password, etc. but I keep getting the error message in the title:

> Invalid connection property value sslmode : require

[image]

I'm not sure what other information to provide? Our connection needs ssl:required setting. I experimented by selecting all available drop down options in the drop down, including `prefer`, `allow`, among others.

How can I overcome this error when the connection requires ssl mode set to required?

Comment: Tested on another client and things work fine with the exact same settings. Now fairly sure this is specific to dbeaver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few months later and gave this another try and found a accidental solution. What's working for me right now is this: I created a brand new connection and forgot to set ssl mode to require, then my connection worked. We do require ssl mode, it seems Dbeaver with aws/redshift driver must default to this. But, as soon as I deliberately go into ssl settings and set this to require, Dbeaver complains per the above with a 'invalid' message.